# Django annotate StrIndex for empty fields

Tags: django, orm, django-orm

I am trying to use Django StrIndex to find all rows with the value a substring of a given string.

Eg:
my table contains:

```
+----------+------------------+
|   user   |      domain      |
+----------+------------------+
| spam1    | spam.com         |
| badguy+  |                  |
|          | protonmail.com   |
| spammer  |                  |
|          | spamdomain.co.uk |
+----------+------------------+
```

but the query

```
SpamWord.objects.annotate(idx=StrIndex(models.Value('xxxx'), 'user')).filter(models.Q(idx__gt=0) | models.Q(domain='spamdomain.co.uk')).first()
```

matches `<SpamWord: *@protonmail.com>`

The query it is `` SELECT `spamwords`.`id`, `spamwords`.`user`, `spamwords`.`domain`, INSTR('xxxx', `spamwords`.`user`) AS `idx` FROM `spamwords` WHERE (INSTR('xxxx', `spamwords`.`user`) > 0 OR `spamwords`.`domain` = 'spamdomain.co.uk') ``

It should be `<SpamWord: *@spamdomain.co.uk>`

this is happening because
`INSTR('xxxx', '')` => 1
(and also `INSTR('xxxxasd', 'xxxx')` => 1, which it is correct)

How can I write this query in order to get entry #5 (spamdomain.co.uk)?

Comment: Shouldn't you swap the parameters, so `idx=StrIndex('user', models.Value('xxxx'))`? The first parameter is the "haystack" the second is the "needle".

Answer (score 0):

The order of the parameters of [**`StrIndex`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#strindex) is swapped. The first parameter is the *haystack*, the string in which you search, and the second one is the *needle*, the substring you are looking for.

You thus can annotate with:

```
from django.db.models import Q, Value

SpamWord.objects.annotate(
    idx=StrIndex('user', Value('xxxx'))
).filter(
    Q(idx__gt=0) | Q(domain='spamdomain.co.uk')
).first()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just filter rows where `user` is empty:

```py
(~models.Q(user='') & models.Q(idx__gt=0)) | models.Q(domain='spamdomain.co.uk')
```